# Why conversion can involve two user defined conversion function/constructor?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer

I am trying to understand which *rules in the standard* justify the compiler behavior below. So this question is only intended to get a **language-lawyer answer.**

Let's consider this two classes:

```
struct A{
   A(int);
};
struct B{
   operator int();
};
```

The following code compile:

```
 B b;
 A a{b};
```

The variable `a` is direct initialized by a `b`. According to [[dlc.init]/17.6.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.6.3):

> Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in [over.match.copy],

I understand that the process of direct initialization will list all *user-defined* conversion sequence that can perform a conversion from `B` (the source type) to `A`, the destination type. [over.match.copy] explain where can be found user defined conversion function.

A *user defined conversion sequence* can only involve 1 user defined conversion function or constructor. But the only conversion path consist in calling both the conversion constructor `A::A(int)` and the conversion function `B::operator int()`.

So there are no user defined conversion sequence that allows conversion from `B` to `A`.

Why according to the standard the initialization `A a{b};` could be well formed?

Comment: There is only one conversion here: `B -> int -> A`...

Comment: Explicitly calling a constructor that takes a argument is not a user defined conversion.  `b` gets converted to an `int` and that `int` is used to call `a`'s constructor.

Comment: @NathanOlivier But the standard says to consider only user defined conversion sequence from B to A. Not user defined conversion sequence from B to a parameter that would match a constructor of A

Comment: I don't have exact language verbiage to quote, but in a nutshell, when the compiler sees `A a{b};`, it first checks if `a` can be directly initialized from `b`, which won't work since `b` is not an instance of `A`, and `A` does not have a `B` member. So then the compiler checks if any constructors of `A` can be called with `b` as input, which does work, via `B::operator int()` and the `A(int)` constructor.  So, the statement `A a{b};` is functionally the same as `A a(b);`  See [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) on cppreference.com

Comment: I think technically it is not direct initialized, but list initialized.

Comment: @Oliv You're looking at the wrong section.  This initialization is covered under the previous bullet: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.6.2

Comment: You mean the preposition should be regrouped as :*Otherwise,( if the initialization is direct-initialization,) (or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination,) constructors are considered* **and not ** (Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization), (or if it is copy-initialization) (where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered)... I have not read correctly

Comment: @Oliv 17.6.2 states *Otherwise, **if the initialization is direct-initialization**, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered.* Since the bold part applies then we read the rest where we have *The applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution.* which explains why it finds `A(int)` and converts `b` to an `int`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Don't know why I had associated the expression *where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class* to both  *the initialization is direct-initialization* and to *copy-initialization*. Which is visibly wrong. Thanks, you solved my problem.

Comment: @Oliv No problem.  Reading the standard can be... exhausting.

Comment: 1) "(i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases)" is a pretty clear indication that you are in the wrong bullet. 2) Actually, @NathanOliver is also in the wrong bullet. This is covered by the very first bullet, [dcl.init]/17.1. The actual initialization here is controlled by [dcl.init.list]/3.6.

Comment: @T.C. Would you look at that.  I didn't scroll up far enough either.

Answer (score 2):

It's well-formed because it uses one conversion to convert from a B to an `int`. Then the constructor for A is called explicitly, using that `int` as a parameter.

This would be a case where you have two user-defined conversions:

```
  void f( A a ) {}
  B b;
  f( b  );
```

Comment: But the standard says to consider only user defined conversion sequence from B to A. Not user defined conversion sequence from B to a parameter that would match a constructor of A.

Comment: The answer is NathanOliver comment, I had miss-read the previous standard bullet which do apply.